# Laravel 5.4 project can't push to heroku because of each function?

Tags: laravel, heroku

When I tried to push to heroku master , this error show me and got rejected push .

```
...
remote:         > php artisan optimize
remote:        [2017-12-01 05:04:43] development.ERROR: ErrorException: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /tmp/build_ad6f98fea0e72e464c86688cdcc423c3/app/Modules/ModulesServiceProvider.php:24
remote:        Stack trace:
...
```

But I don't write that `each(deprecated)` function so I don't know where to remove it !

My project is laravel 5.4

Comment: have you checked `app/Modules/ModulesServiceProvider.php` ?

Comment: In the `ModulesServiceProvider.php` you may change modify `each()` to a `foreach()`. The `each()` function is deprecated as of PHP 7.2.

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_2#each